# How to group form data before posting it

Tags: javascript, html, forms, express, post

I want to group my data by my div rows into JSON objects and I am unsure if it is possible with just HTML, I do not have any front end javascript to edit data that I post before it happens. I am unsure if it is possible or not.

My HTML:

```
<form action="/post-data" method="post">
    <div class="form-row">
        <input name="item" type="text">
        <input name="count" type="number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input name="item" type="text">
        <input name="count" type="number">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

The data I receive from this form is:

`{ item: [ 'item one', 'item two'], count: [ '12', '123'] }`

The data I want to receive:

```
[
    {
        name: 'item one',
        count: '12'
    }, {
        name: 'item two',
        count: '123'
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in object structure. Assign names with general one. Like:

```
<form action="/post-data" method="post">
    <div class="form-row">
        <input name="entry1.item" type="text">
        <input name="entry1.count" type="number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input name="entry2.item" type="text">
        <input name="entry2.count" type="number">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

You also may use any framework that keeps the state between controller and view. Or send form not from html but using `javascript` and `ajax`.